# DC on Hyper V Host

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I've read a few similar questions but wasn't clear. I have a small office (13) users and recently purchased a new single server (this is all I have to work with for now).

**Server specs**

- Memory - 16G
- Drives - 6 SCSI (2TB)
- Processor - Dual Quad Core

I plan on making the Hyper-V host the DC and then 2 VMs, one for a file server and the other an application server.

Question - since I am restricted to this single server, would it be a big issue making the Hyper-V host the domain controller?

Your input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the scenario you describe would work, the "best practice" approach is to not run *any* roles on the Hyper-V host other than Hyper-V; all services should run on virtual machines running on the Hyper-V host.

The hardware you describe should be more than capable of running three Hyper-V hosts; especially since a dedicated DC for 13 users would require minimal disk and memory resources.

The best option would be to obtain a single [Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/2008-ent.aspx) license; this would entitle you to install the Hyper-V role on the hardware as well as up to four additional virtual instances of Windows Server 2008 R2 running on your Hyper-V host with no additional licensing cost.

If, however, you plan to use existing licenses for your application and file servers, another option would be to install [Hyper-V Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/how-to-get.aspx) on the hardware to host your virtual servers. Hyper-V Server is free to download and use; however, no licensing is  included, so any virtual machines you create must be individually licensed. Hyper-V Server is based upon Server Core, so the footprint and exposed surface area are very small. The UI provided with Hyper-V Server will assist in configuration of the machine for remote management; in this scenario, you will create and manage virtual machines on Hyper-V Server using the Hyper-V Manager MMC from your workstation. (Microsoft provides good information on this topic in the [Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 Getting Started Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee815289(WS.10).aspx))

Comment: Agreed, although the standalone Hyper-V hypervisor is totally free, and comes with all of the features you would require for the number of VMs being talked about here.

Comment: Good point, Farseeker... while Enterprise licensing would offer both expandability and flexibility, those features may not be valued--particularly if Saif has already obtained two Windows 2008 Standard licenses! A good approach would be to deploy Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 on the hardware and install two Windows 2008 Standard virtual machines; the Active Directory role could then be added to the file server virtual machine.

Comment: And go with the Core installation for the host.  Minimizes the host utilization and management factor.

Comment: I've edited the response to include information offered in comments and provide a couple more links to relevant information...

Comment: @Holocryptic, Hyper-V Server doesn't have a core type install, it's already more stripped down than core. MS chose poor names for the OS and the Service.

Comment: @Chris S Blast... Thanks for the correction.  I'll have to do some research on that now.  I was looking at this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753802(WS.10).aspx, so that's probably where I went wrong.

Comment: You can install Server 2008 R2 in either a "full install" with Hyper-V (convenient if you plan to manage things from the host partition) or a "core install" with the Hyper-V role; doing so provides you with additional functionality and licensing rights depending on whether you use Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter editions. The discussion above focuses on "Hyper-V Server 2008 R2" which is a separate free-to-download-and-use product that has a (rather robust) subset of the functionality and limited licensing rights. It is not a "core install" but is "core-like" in that it has a minimal UI.

Comment: It's a Server 2008 R2 full install with hyper-v role. I dont have any Vista or Win 7 at the mement, only XP clients...so the core install is out at the moment. I want to make the hyper-v host the DC.

Comment: Ah, so you will manage Hyper-V from the host partition; that will work fine (and is how I built my first few Hyper-V hosts)... What "Edition" (Standard, Enterprise, etc.) is your 2008 R2 install with Hyper-V?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are talkling about hyper-v Server 2008 (not Windows Server 2008 with hyper-v role enabled).  If so I think you will have no domain until you have the DC running within one of the VMs.

To administer the hypervisor (using Hyper-V manager MMC from your workstation) you will need to set up a workgroup to manage the VM's until they are running.  It can be done (that's how I manage my hyper-v server at home) but you will probably need to use the HVRemote power shell scripts to get it setup.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the annoying issues with actually getting connected management to a Hyper-V Server that's not yet in a domain... kinda catch 22 thingie when you "need" a domain to easily managed Hyper-V Server but you need to manage it to set up a virtual DC and domain ^^

Comment: I am talking about Windows Server 2008 with hyper-v role enabled. I want to make that server a primary DC, then just add 2 additional VMs.

Answer (score 1):

Works, but I would NOT Move the file server to a vm - what for?

I have a similar setup(just 2 computers) here, and I use the DC also as file server. As all file acces is via DFS anyway (so the server name is never part of file access) this has no negatives, and I save having a VM just to provide a function that is core to the OS anyway.