# Hyper-V Server 2008 Configuration

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I need to set-up Lync on a Server 2008 machine.  The problem is that Lync cannot be set up on a Domain Controller.  That means I need to have one Server 2008 that's a domain controller and another that's Server 2008 running Lync.

I figured the best way would be hosting it on a single machine, using virtual machines.

I installed Server 2008, but now my question is this.  Do I add two virtual machines (Domain Controller and Lync), or do I only add one virtual machine for Lync, and the 'parent' Server 2008 can act as a domain controller?

Comment: if this is for test purposes then just create two vm's, if this is production then you could still do this but some would say thats not a good idea but it seems like you are on a limited budget, so run to vm's.

Comment: @tonyroth So is it possible to have a running server with VM, or do I need two VMs?

Comment: According to the following answer, the best practice seems to be running all roles under virtual hosts:

http://serverfault.com/questions/143161/dc-on-hyper-v-host?rq=1

So in my scenario I should run DC and Lync in their own VMs.

Comment: yes in my 1st statement I said "to" meant two :) but hopefully you are not going production with this right?

Answer (score 3):

Zeroeth rule of Domain Controllers: **always have at least 2 domain controllers!**

First rule of Domain Controllers: **don't install anything on a domain controller** besides the roles to support Active Directory, antivirus and the client for your network monitoring software. This server should not serve any purpose other than being a Domain Controller. (There is a valid argument for hosting some services such as DHCP (small businesses or satellite offices) and KMS, but anything else is probably a bad idea.)

Second rule of Domain Controllers: **do not virtualize all of your domain controllers**. You should have at least one physical domain controller. If you run in to problems with a virtualization host server, you'll need a domain controller around to be able to log in. And Windows Failover Clustering (generally) requires a domain controller to be present to start up.

Applying the above to your situation: having the domain controller also act as the virtulization host definitely violates the first rule, and possibly the second.

Obviously if this is a test environment where you don't mind the whole thing coming down in flames all around you, feel free to ignore this advice.